# TimerTask : оповещение по заданному времени и дате в Android

Tags: android, уведомления

Есть задача показать оповещение в определенную дату и время которые указывает пользователь. При попытке сделать через TimerTask не выходит показать оповещение в нужное время.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2)));
            thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)));
            thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6,10)));
            thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)));
            thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3, 5)));

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ToDoActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("Напоминание MyNotes")
                    .setContentText(description);

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notification);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, thatDay.getTime());
```

Если в `timer.schedule` передавать просто задержку в милисекундах, то работает
Но при попытке указать разницу между датами в милисекунах

```
thatDay.getTimeInMillisec() - System.currentTimeInMillisec()
```

получаю ошибку, `delay < 0`

Если указать `thatDay.getTime()` вторым параметром, то оповещение выполняется сразу же, но не в указанное время..

P.S. Время и дата строками заданы ("26/12/2015", "15:00")

Comment: В вашем текущем коде весь разбор строки и инициализация даты выполняется внутри `TimerTask.run`, т.е. код, который проинициализирует дату выполнится, только когда сработает таймер и выполнится задание.

Comment: Спасибо, вынес разбор даты выше метода, но оповещение теперь совсем не появляется

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментариq в виде ответа.